# headless chrome + rspec not able to select option form select list it gives error capybara element not found

Tags: google-chrome, rspec, capybara

I am using **headless chrome**, **rspec - 3.6.0**, **capybara - 2.15.1**

```
select('apple',from: 'fruits', visible: false)
page.find('#apple', visible: false).click
within 'results' do
  page.find('.option', text: 'apple').click
end
```

**Error:**

```
 Capybara::ElementNotFound: Unable to find visible css "#fruits .chosen-drop .chosen-results"
```

Comment: solved as page.execute_script("$('#fruits').val('apple')")

Comment: That’s not a solution, it’s a bandaid which makes the writing of the test pointless

Answer (score 0):

The error shown in your question is not from any of the other lines of code you show, however based on the error message it's pretty clear what's going on.

Attempting to perform any action on an element you've found using `visible: false` makes no sense because the user can't interact with a non-visible element (99% of time if you specify `visible: false` you're doing something wrong). In the current case you are using the `chosen` library which hides the normal HTML <select> element and replaces it with a JS driven widget made up of <ul> and <li> elements. Because of this you can't use the normal `select` method and instead need to interact with the page just like a normal user would (click on the 'chosen' field and then click on the element from the list). You haven't provided the actual HTML generated for your page, but based on your attempts and the output generated by the `chosen` demo page - https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/ - it will be something like

```
<select id="fruits" ... style="display: none;>
  ...
</select>
<div class="chosen-container" ... >
  ...
  <div class="chosen-drop">
    ...
    <ul class="chosen-results">
      <li ...>Apple</li>
      <li ...>Orange</li>
      ...
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

So to work with that the user would first need to click on the `.chosen-conatiner` element (sibling of the hidden select) to open the `.chosen-drop` element and then click on the correct <li> from the `.chosen-results` element which translates into something like

```
chosen_container = find('select#fruits + .chosen-container').click
chosen_container.find('.chosen-results li', exact_text: 'Apple').click
```

If that doesn't work for you then you'll need to add the exact HTML from your live page to your question.

Note: if you're dealing with a lot of `chosen` widgets in your site you may want to look into writing custom Capybara selectors -https://www.rubydoc.info/github/teamcapybara/capybara/Capybara#add_selector-class_method - to make the tests read a lot better

Comment: my select box is at the bottom of the page I tried page.execute_script 'window.scrollBy(0,100)' and used capybara to select but it did not worked. but 'page.execute_script("$('#fruits').val('apple')")' is working

Comment: @sid What does “did not work” mean? What error from which line of code? Of course using JS to set the value will work but it makes the actual test worthless because you’re doing something a user could never do.